# Checking PEAR version

Tags: shell, stdout, pear

I'm writing server automation script using Chef, and I need to check the installed version of the PEAR package manager. The command line switch `-V` prints the detailed version information to the console:

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ubuntu-lucid-32-generic 2.6.32-33-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:08:37 UTC 2011 i686
```

However, I'm unable to isolate the `1.9.0` part of that result and test against it. The pear script doesn't seem to be printing to STDOUT, since redirection isn't working either:

```
$ pear -V > pear_version
PEAR Version 1.9.0
...
$ cat pear_version
$
```

How can I capture the output and pass it to grep so I can return just "1.9.0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming your shell is a linux/unix variant like bash)

I  don't have pear to test with but I would guess that the missing version info is going to STDERR, so try

```
 pearVer=$(pear -V 2>&1 | sed '/^PEAR Version: /s///')
```

This only matches lines that begin with 'PEAR Version'. the 's///' is short hand for, 'match the first expression and replace it with '//' (nothing).

I hope this helps.